php while loop inside foreach only executes on first loop
I have an array of values and I use a while loop to lookup a CSV file for each of those values and make a list of any matches
But, for some reason the while loop only executes for the first foreach loop - all subsequent loops just exit with nothing ---
        foreach ($selectedpaths as $path) {
            
            echo "<BR>working on this: " . $path . "<BR>";      

            #run through the csv
            while ($row = fgetcsv($allroutes)) {            
                
                echo ".";               

                #fetch entries that match
                if ($row[5] == $path) {
                    echo "<BR>" .$row[5] . " == " . $path ."    MATCH   " . $row . "<BR>";
                }
            }
        }

This is the output from that code:
working on this: test1
.....................................................................................
test1 == test1 MATCH A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,test1
........................................
test1 == test1 MATCH A6,B6,C6,D6,E1,test1
.......................................................................
test1 == test1 MATCH A68,B68,C68,D68,E1,test1
..............................................................................................................................................................................................................
working on this: test2

working on this: test3

working on this: test4

I can see from the "working on this: X" that it definitely is looping through each of the lookups in turn
But even if it finds no matches, it should still be outputting the dots to say its at least looping though the csv to try..... but it outputs nothing after the first loop
I would understand if it never worked but why does it work the first time round? Is it something weird about how php executes while loops?

The first time through, you consume the entire file $allroutes. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php

Regarding your new question here I don't know why they deleted our content, it's awful! However here is my answer again. You can use ^(?>.*\d)([a-z]+) or a more compatible regex with capturing group: \d([a-z]+)\D*$ (PHP demo)

Thanks @bobblebubble - I've no idea why they closed that, the answers they provided were not even in the same language

The file pointer already reached the end of the file the first time around, so this has no more rows to return:
fgetcsv($allroutes)

Presumably somewhere before this you called something like this to open the file stream:
$allroutes = fopen("some_file.csv", "r")

You could rewind the stream to the start of the file before trying to loop over it again:
rewind($allroutes);
// the while loop here

Or potentially move the entire file-opening operation into the foreach loop:
$allroutes = fopen("some_file.csv", "r")
// the while loop here

(The latter approach is probably slower.  For small scales the difference is likely negligible and can be weighed against the clarity of the surrounding logic.)

As you read the file inside the loop, the next time you would have to read the file again for the next comparison.
It looks like if you could read the file and just checking if the path is in the list of paths (using in_array())...
      #run through the csv
      while ($row = fgetcsv($allroutes)) {            
          #fetch entries that match
          if (in_array($row[5], $selectedpaths)) {

              echo "<BR>" .$row[5] . "    MATCH   " . $row . "<BR>";
          }
      }

with this method, you don't need the outer loop.

I think you're missing a fseek($allroutes, 0); from your solution.

@symcbean, didn't think so, where do you think it's needed?

thanks for this - I think it would definitely be more efficent than the way I'm doing it

As others have said, this happens because, on the first loop, the file pointer reached the end of the file, and there's nothing else to read.
Nigen Ren's approach is cleaner, and will be definitely faster, since it only reads the file once.
Now, in case you really need to process elements in the order of the $selectedpaths array, one suggestion would be to load the file into another array, and then use it in the loop:
$routes = array();
while ($row = fgetcsv($allroutes)) {            
    $routes[] = $row;
}
foreach ($selectedpaths as $path) {
    echo "<BR>working on this: " . $path . "<BR>";      
    #run through the csv
    echo ".";               
    #fetch entries that match
    foreach ($routes as $row) {
        if ($row[5] == $path) {
            echo "<BR>" .$row[5] . " == " . $path ."    MATCH   " . $row . "<BR>";
        }
    }
}

